# Meteor js working with SOAP webservice using zardak/meteor-soap

Tags: meteor, soap

I'm developing meteorjs app, that use magento SOAP API v2 using zardak/meteor-soap package, and I have troubles with sending messages. It seems, meteor-soap implementation proceeds incorrectly message's fields which are array of strings.

I try to send "customerAddressCreateRequest" message. In WSDL it is appeared as follow:

```html
<message name="customerAddressCreateRequest">
  <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="customerId" type="xsd:int"/>
  <part name="addressData" type="typens:customerAddressEntityCreate"/>
</message>
 ...

<complexType name="customerAddressEntityCreate">
 <all>
  <element name="city" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <element name="company" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>

  <!-- a lot of fields  -->

  <element name="street" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>

  <!-- a lot of fields again -->
 </all>
</complexType>
```

Take a look on "street" field's type...

When I try to play with API from Boomerang Chrome app, it generate followed message for me:

```html
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <urn:customerAddressCreate>
             <urn:sessionId>40831216c3ecbe4200e43bf0155fc50c</urn:sessionId>
            <urn:customerId>47</urn:customerId>
            <urn:addressData>
                <urn:city>SomeCity</urn:city>
                <urn:company>SomeCompany</urn:company>
                <urn:country_id>10</urn:country_id>
                <urn:fax>332266554455</urn:fax>
                <urn:firstname>Vasya</urn:firstname>
                <urn:lastname>Pupkin</urn:lastname>
                <urn:middlename></urn:middlename>
                <urn:postcode>36500</urn:postcode>
                <urn:prefix></urn:prefix>
                <urn:region_id>1</urn:region_id>
                <urn:region>Neverland</urn:region>
                <urn:street>
                    <urn:string>Some st.</urn:string>
                </urn:street>
                <urn:suffix></urn:suffix>
                <urn:telephone>+8100816645875</urn:telephone>
                <urn:is_default_billing>false</urn:is_default_billing>
                <urn:is_default_shipping>true</urn:is_default_shipping>
            </urn:addressData>
        </urn:customerAddressCreate>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

... and it works like a charm :-) (notice how street field is appeared)

but, when I try to send the same request from code:

```js
client.customerAddressCreate({
  sessionId: soapConnection.sessionId,
  customerId: customerId,
  addressData: {
    city: 'SomeCity',
    company: 'SomeCompany',
    country_id: '10',
    fax: '332266554455',
    firstname: 'Vasya',
    lastname: 'Pupkin',
    middlename: "",
    postcode: '36500',
    prefix: '',
    region_id: '1',
    region: 'Neverland',
    street: ['Some st.'],
    suffix: '',
    telephone: '+8100816645875',
    is_default_billing: false,
    is_default_shipping: true,
  }
}, (err, result, raw) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(result)
  console.log(raw)
})
```

I obtain the follow message that is sent to magento:

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:typens="urn:Magento">
 <soap:Body>
  <typens:customerAddressCreate>
   <sessionId>7dccb43aa9a5ff304919acc657c89e3d</sessionId>
   <customerId>85</customerId>
   <addressData>
    <city>SomeCity</city>
    <company>SomeCompany</company>
    <country_id>10</country_id>
    <fax>332266554455</fax>
    <firstname>Vasya</firstname>
    <lastname>Pupkin</lastname>
    <middlename></middlename>
    <postcode>36500</postcode>
    <prefix></prefix>
    <region_id>1</region_id>
    <region>Neverland</region>
    <street>Some st.</street>
    <suffix></suffix>
    <telephone>+8100816645875</telephone>
    <is_default_billing>false</is_default_billing>
    <is_default_shipping>true</is_default_shipping>
   </addressData>
  </typens:customerAddressCreate>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Take a look onto street field again.

As you can see, meteor-soap package put array of string as simple string. And as result, I obtain Error message from magento, that claims about missed street value. 
What I have missed? How I can to make soap-client to send correct request?

Thanks.